# How can i prevent "Download of Code Without Integrity Check" at Class.forName("classname")

Tags: java, security, checkmarx

My code scanning by **CheckMarx** and **"Download of Code Without Integrity Check"** problem occured at;

```
Class.forName("blabla");
```

or

```
urlClassLoader.loadClass("blabla");
```

My system design need this features, I have to use these.

How can i prevent this issue?

Thanks for help.

Comment: https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/494.html "This code does not ensure that the class loaded is the intended one, for example by verifying the class's checksum". How do you plan to ensure that the class loaded is the intended one?

Comment: Actually I loaded my own classes in there, these classes placed in my server, not from outside.